# Is there an excel function for turning equations in the cell to a text or string form

Tags: excel, excel-formula

so I have a project with excel file where i have multiple equations. I need to do print screen and copy paste into a google docs with the answers and the equations used. so in the first pic it will have all the numbers and the second pic will have the equations used to get those numbers.

so for example the first picture would be like this where all the numbers are present

[image]

the second picture I need is something like this where the answers I got need to show the equations used

[image]

I was wondering if there was a faster way then manually deleting the "=" sign and leaving the values unchanged.

I tried YouTube but most of it was something completely different.

Comment: You can use `FORMULATEXT` in a separate cell? Or `Ctrl+~`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Formulas tab, there is a button, Show formulas. You can toggle the formulas with that.